# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'map' and 'float'

Tags: python

I was practicing `tesorflow` on Colaboratory and my code is as below.
There is some issue, the error message is

> "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'map' and 'float'"

Can someone tell me what's wrong? thanks!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(20)
y = map(lambda x: x + np.random.randn(1), x)
a, b = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
plt.plot(x, y, 'o', np.arange(20), a*np.arange(20)+b, '-');**
```

Comment: Are you on Python 3? You cannot pass a `map` object to `np.polyfit`, it expects an array-like object. What does this have to do with tensorflow?

Comment: Please show the FULL traceback when posting error messages, or at least say which line it is coming from.  BTW, if you convert `y` to a `list` it then fails in the `plt.plot` with `ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension`

Comment: Please click address below.
https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/welcome.ipynb#scrollTo=xqrc5C-IaA5J

Comment: @PingyaoChen: no I can't, it asks me to logon to a Google account.  Anyway, that code is probably written for Python 2 where `map()` returned a list object, in Python 3 it returns a `map` object.

Comment: You're right. I found the answer.
Python2 is return list, Python3 is return map. 
so need add a list to convert it.
y = list(map(lambda x: x + np.random.randn(1), x))

Answer (score 5):

the 'Colaboratory Introduction' is writed by Python2, as @cdarke said, map() return a map object in Python3. So you should trans the map obj to a list. Replace the code like this:

```
y = list(map(lambda x: x + np.random.randn(1), x))
```

Answer (score 2):

In [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map), `map()` returns an iterable while, in [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#map), it returns a list. Any mathematical operation, like numpy's `polyfit()`, between a python iterable and a float number would throw similar error. The line:

```
a, b = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
```

throws the mentioned error in Python 3 as `y` is an iterable returned by the function `map()`. It is likely that you are working in Python 3. So you need to convert `y` into list before any mathematical operation, like so, `np.polyfit(x, list(y), 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

try replacing

```
y = map(input1(x), x)
```

with

```
y = map(input1, x)
```